# Jordan decomposition for linear functionals on $C^*$-algebras

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

When $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space, there is a Jordan decomposition theorem for the dual of $C_0(X,R)$. If we consider a unital algebra $A$, $\tau$ is a linear functional on $A$, does there exist a Jordan decomposition for $\tau$?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for the lemma in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pja/1195526177), "every bounded linear functional can be expressed by a finite linear combination of states". I believe Takeda and Grothendieck obtained this result independently.